# Forms en django: como asignar un valor a un campo

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, multichoice, django-class-based-views

soy bastante novato en Django, quiza alguien me pueda responder:
Tengo al siguienta clase en models.py para crear mi base de datos

```
class BookInstance(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    book = models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    LOAN_STATUS = (
        ('o', 'En prestamo'),
        ('a', 'Disponible'),
        ('r', 'Reservado'),
    )
    status = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices = LOAN_STATUS, blank = True, default='a')
```

En mi apliación tengo usuarios comunes, y un usario administrador. El administrados puede cambiar el estado del libro a los 3 posibles. Pero el usuario común solo debería poder reservarlo
En views.py tengo la siguiente clase para gestionar el prestamo de un libro

```
class ToLoanBook(PermissionRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    model = BookInstance
    permission_required = 'gestion.can_mark_returned'
    form_class = ToLoanBookForm
    template_name = 'gestion/loan-book.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('all-borrowed')
```

Como puedo hacer para que cuando se llame a esta clase, y el usuario logeado no sea el administrador, no le de las opciones sino que lo fije a 'r' directamente? No se si es posible asignarle un valor a un campo de una clase, como si fuese una variable donde yo pueda hacer status = 'r' o algo asi
Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si solo quieres que se fije a reservado(`r`) directamente el campo `status`, entonces no veo necesidad de mostrar el campo, a un usuario que no es el admin.

Una manera de hacer que por defecto el valor de campo `status` sea `r`, seria especificandolo en el mismo campo (`models.CharField(default='r')`) y simplemente no mostrar el campo al usuario no administrador.

Pero si no quieres cambiar el `default` a `"r"` en el campo (ya que lo tienes por defecto a `"a"`), podrías hacerlo en la vista, de la siguiente manera (no mostrando el campo):

```
class ToLoanBook(PermissionRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    model = BookInstance
    permission_required = 'gestion.can_mark_returned'
    form_class = ToLoanBookForm
    template_name = 'gestion/loan-book.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('all-borrowed')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Entramos al if si el usuario autenticado no es admin
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            form.instance.status = 'r' # Damos el valor de "r" al campo status

        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Y en el form seria así:

```
<form method="POST">
    ...
    {% if user.is_superuser %}
        {{ form.status }}
    {% endif %}
</form>
```

De esta manera si el usuario autenticado en ese momento, es super usuario o admin se le mostrara el campo `status`, por lo cual podrá seleccionar cualquiera de las opciones dadas, y si no lo es, simplemente no mostrara el campo.

Y en la vista si el usuario no es super usuario, asigna como valor `"r"` al campo `status`, ya que el usuario normal no habrá seleccionado ningún valor.

---

Por otra parte, si quieres que aparezca el campo `status` y que este seleccionado por defecto la opción "Reservado" si el usuario autenticado no es admin, seria así, en la vista:

```
class ToLoanBook(PermissionRequiredMixin,generic.UpdateView):
    model = BookInstance
    permission_required = 'gestion.can_mark_returned'
    form_class = ToLoanBookForm
    template_name = 'gestion/loan-book.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('all-borrowed')

    def get_form(self, form_class = None):
        form = super().get_form(form_class)

        # Entramos al if si el usuario autenticado no es admin
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            form.fields['status'].disabled = True # Desabilitamos el campo status
            form.fields['status'].choices = [('r', 'Reservado')] # Le damos solo una opcion al campo status

        return form
```

De esta manera si el usuario no es admin o super usuario, aparecerá el campo `status` en el form, PERO de solo lectura y estará ya seleccionado por defecto la opción "Reservado" y con su respectivo valor `"r"`.

Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: El primer caso funcionó perfecto para mi cometido. No he encontrado información, tutoriales, cursos, ni siquiera en la web oficial de django, como se pueden reescribir métodos, y cuales son los que se pueden reescribir según tu lo hiciste. Se agradece cualquier otra información al respecto que puedas tenes. Saludos

Comment: Recuerda aceptar mi pregunta si resolvió tu problema o duda :)

Comment: Julio Cesar, tu respuesta me sirvió mucho. Como acepto tu pregunta?

Comment: En la parte izquierda de mi respuesta hay un visto, da click ahí, y aceptaras la pregunta. :)

Comment: En mi respuesta, marca el check al costado, que tiene forma de visto, para aceptar mi respuesta :).